# ASP.NET MVC Routing giving dir listing at root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I've got the following routes:

```
// Submission/*
routes.MapRoute(
    "Submission",
    "Submission/{form}",
    new { controller = "Submission", action = "Handle", form = "" });

// /<some-page>
routes.MapRoute(
    "Pages",
    "{page}",
    new { controller = "Main", action = "Page", page = "Index" });
```

The first routes requests exactly as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263635/route-all-controller-actions-to-a-single-method-then-display-a-view-according-to) question.  The second generically routes a bunch of static content pages.  For instance localhost/Help, localhost/Contact, etc. all route to the MainController which simply returns the view according to the page name:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Page()
    {
        var page = (string)RouteData.Values["page"];
        return View(page);
    }
}
```

The problem is, during testing at least, localhost/ gives a dir listing instead of routing to Main/Index.aspx. The real problem is it fubars my SiteMap menu because the URLs aren't matching what's defined in the Web.sitemap file.  localhost/Index does give me the correct view, however.

The curious thing is this works as expected on Mono / XSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  There were (potentially) two things going awry.  One, the project must have the MVC project type GUID.  Check out [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/01/20/opening-an-asp-net-mvc-project-without-having-asp-net-mvc-installed-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation.aspx) for an idea - though the post isn't quite on topic.  Two, Visual Studio 2008 requires SP1 for an updated ASP.NET development server; the version of it prior to SP1 doesn't kick off Global.asax w/o a Default.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing it using Visual Studio Dev Server than it should work. I have tried it just now.

On IIS neither of "localhost/" and "localhost/Index" should work unless you enabled [wildcard mapping](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

So it works for me. You probably are missing something that is not obvious from the post.

BTW, your action can be improved:

```
public ActionResult Page(string page)
{
    return View(page);
}
```

**EDIT:** [Here](http://nagir.bravehost.com/public/MVC/MvcApplication1.zip) is my sample project.

Comment: Upvoted for the tip at least. I can't think of anything that I'm missing ... Mono seems to like it just fine. Can you attach your project so I can test locally?

Comment: Hrm ... archive isn't unzipping properly.

Comment: Ohh, mate sorry. I'll be able to reupload only on Monday (I'm home now and have no any dev tools here). But what I did is:

1. Create default MVC app.
2. Added MainController as you provided.
3. Removed all the routes in Global.asax.cs and replaced them with your ones.
4. Tested and it did work.